# Gradle Performance: Duplicating Dependencies with Implementation vs Reusing and Exposing with API

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, dagger-2

I am creating a common module for Android that will use Dagger 2 which provide for example Retrofit client. Now on the Dagger 2 documentation it is stated

> We use implementation instead of api for better compilation performance.

Which they also include a Gradle [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation).

It pointed out the following for using `implementation`

- dependencies do not leak into the compile classpath of consumers anymore, so you will never accidentally depend on a transitive dependency
- faster compilation thanks to reduced classpath size
- less recompilations when implementation dependencies change: consumers would not need to be recompiled
- cleaner publishing: when used in conjunction with the new maven-publish plugin, Java libraries produce POM files that distinguish exactly between what is required to compile against the library and what is required to use the library at runtime (in other words, don’t mix what is needed to compile the library itself and what is needed to compile against the library).

The reason I am planning to use `api` instead of `implementation` is to avoid duplicating the dependency on consumer (app module) if it is already exist in common module. But after reading the documentation it seems duplicating it on consumer (app module) is much better instead of exposing and reusing the dependencies available from common module.

Is duplicating the dependency is better than exposing it using `api`?

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume we have your library U, which makes use of another library O.

To my understanding `api` should be used only, when you expose declarations of a library (O) as part of your (U) libraries public interface. Consumers must know the types of the other library (O) to make use of your library (U).

When you use a library (O) just internally to implement the functionality of your library (U), it's an `implementation` detail, which should not be leaked to the consumers of your library (U). You should be able to completely replace it without any consumer noticing the chance, as long as your public api remains unchanged.

---

Let's give an example. Assume we have two libraries O, one which is used on the public api of U *o-model* and another which is used just internally *o-utils*.

*o-model*

```kotlin
data class User(
    val id: UUID,
    val name: String,
    val salary: Int,
    val birthday: LocalDate
)
```

*o-utils*

```kotlin
infix fun Int.increasedBy(value: Int) = this + value
```

Your library U might look something along the lines of:

```kotlin
fun increaseSalary(user: User, amount: Int): User =
    user.copy(
        salary = user.salary increasedBy amount
    )
```

The declaration of `data class User` from *o-model* is leaked to the outsides of your library U and thus should be known to the consumer of your library U. However, that you use `increaseSalary` of *o-utils* to implement your functionality is of no concern to the consumer. You may change this at any time.

In your `build.gradle.kts` this should be declared as:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    // available on the compile classpath of the consumers
    api("com.example:o-model")
    // available only during the runtime
    implementation("com.example:o-utils")
}
```

---

To me, it's more a question of architecture and modularization, rather than optimization. Note that the optimization noted in the Gradle documentation you've cited is mostly about *compilation times*. This is most likely not the culprit of slow build times and there are [other, more efficient optimizations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/performance.html) one can apply to ones Gradle build.

---

Thus, if the library in question *Dagger 2* is part of the public api of your library (U), it should be declared as `api`, otherwise it should not. In both cases it will be on the runtime classpath, as it is necessary for your library (U) to work.
If you just need *Dagger 2* in multiple projects but not your library (U) itself, you might rather look at other alternatives for [sharing dependencies between projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html).

Comment: Where's the example?